# achartengine: line chart with threshold

Tags: android, achartengine, threshold, linegraph

I use achartengine in my Android application and has been able to draw few line charts. Now I need to draw some kind of threshold line which basically an extra line in red that will run at certain Y value across the graph.

I read other questions regarding threshold lines but mostly about bar chart to have different color above and below threshold line. I need it for line chart and I don't need different color above and below the threshold line.

I can definitely draw it as another line, but I don't want legend for this shows up while I still want legend for others show up. Is there any way to do this? I don't know if there is built-in functionality to draw the threshold line. Or at least a way to hide legend for only one line.

Any input, suggestion or direction will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. If anyone needs to do the same thing, this is what I do:

```
if(i == theIndexForThresholdLine) {
    renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setShowLegendItem(false);
}
```

That will turn off legend only for that item.